# Passing events without direct reference to the listener

Tags: java, events

I would like to pass an event from a wicket component to it's parent, without having a direct reference to it's parent.

Java's observable patterns and events/listeners always seems to have a direct reference to the observer or listener.

Is it possible to throw a specific event and catch it, just like exceptions, without having to use exceptions?

(I can't using wicket atmosphere yet, because I'm using an wicket version 6.14 and wicket atmosphere is in alpha)

Comment: Usually with event frameworks there's some manager which has a direct reference to all the listeners and will call them as necessary. I'm not familiar with wicket, but you would need to create some kind of manager that can be provided with some flag which, when inspected, will tell it to call a particular listener. The object that creates the flag doesn't need to care about the listener or how he gets it, but just know about the manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used an abstract class instead of using events.
Instead of directly referring to  parent (caller) class, I implemented the method that needed that reference on instantiation.

E.g:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    ParentPanel.this.doSomething();
}
```